# How to properly update list of tabs compose

Tags: android, tabs, android-jetpack-compose

I get a list of folders from the network and display it using tabs. How can I correctly redraw the tabs when I receive a new list? It may be a different size and with different folder names.

```
val selectedTabIndex = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    
        val tabs = 
            listOf("Folder 1", "Folder 2", "Folder 3", "Folder 4", "Folder 5", "Folder 6", "Folder 7")
                .toMutableStateList()
    
        Row {
            ScrollableTabRow(
                selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex.intValue,
                contentColor = Color.LightGray,
                edgePadding = 0.dp
            ) {
                tabs.forEachIndexed { tabIndex, tab ->
                    Tab(
                        selected = selectedTabIndex.intValue == tabIndex,
                        onClick = { selectedTabIndex.intValue = tabIndex },
                        text = { Text(text = tab) }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared tabs as follows:

```
val tabs = listOf("Folder 1", "Folder 2", "Folder 3").toMutableStateList()
```

This is equivalent to the more common syntax as follows:

```
val tabs = remember { mutableStateListOf("Folder 1", "Folder 2", "Folder 3") }
```

As a result, Jetpack Compose will properly observe the changes that happen to the tabs variable. Whenever you change the list by adding or removing an item, this will trigger a recomposition, and all Composables that depend on the tabs variable will be redrawn.

```
tabs.add("Folder 8")
```

As a result,

- the `forEachIndexed` function will be re-executed and
- thus the `Tab` Composables will be updated.

However, you might want to make sure manually that `selectedTabIndex` does not point to an invalid index. As of now, if you remove items from the `tabs` list, it could happen that no `Tab` is selected anymore. You can try it as follows:

```
val tabs = ...

// use "by" keyword to directly access the value property
var selectedTabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
// at every Recomposition, we make sure that the selectedTabIndex is in range
selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex.coerceIn(0, tabs.size - 1)
```

A small side note, once you add some content to the tabs, you might will need to use the `key` function to [properly preserve the state when adding or removing tabs](https://medium.com/@android-world/understanding-the-key-function-in-jetpack-compose-34accc92d567).

Comment: @BenijTec thank you, it worked! this will be accepted as the correct answer)